# send an email with ajax when closing a page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

hi at my work i need to send a mail when the customer close the page or  press F5, for this i used this code in the script in the header of the page:

```
var from = <?PHP echo $from; ?>;
var to = <?PHP echo $to;?>;

$( window ).unload(function() {
  return sendMail(from, to);
});
```

the function in the JS:

```
function sendMail(from, to) {
var modif = $("#mailBody").val();
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax_client_pour_courtier.php',
    method: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        type: 'sendMail',
        from: from,
        to: to,
        modif: modif
    },
```

and the "ajax_client_pour_courtier.php":

```
    if (isset($_POST['type'])) {
    switch ($_POST['type']) {
      case 'sendMail':
          if(TClientsPourCourtier::sendMail($_POST['from'], $_POST['to'], $_POST['modif'])) {
            echo '{"ok": "ok"}';
          } else {
            echo '{"error": "error"}';
          }
          break;
```

so when i called sendMail() with an onclick="" it's working but when i use unload() the console send me this error: "XHR failed loading: POST",
i hope someone can help me to fix this and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: The 'unload' event is fired when a web page has been unloaded, try the 'beforeunload' event.

Comment: its working and it was easy for you (-_-'), thx again i just lost 4h on this.

Comment: That's good. We all have to learn, I often spent four hours on other easy stuff. :-) It's often the only way to learn, so the time is not really lost.

Comment: woops my bad, its working only with F5 not when i close the page

Comment: Ah, yes, that can happen. But now you know what the problem is: Event is not fired or the DOM is not in the correct state. Closing the browser could be different from jumping to another page or F5.

Comment: What you're basically doing with an Ajax call is calling another page. As long as the browser stays open it will do that, but if you close the browser the other page may never be called.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27696675/how-to-handle-socket-io-disconnect-by-client-by-leaving-page

Comment: yes i think about something like that can i force a delay before close ? or maybe a dialog for confirm mail sending i will try this

Comment: No, I don't think there's anything you can do to stop a browser from closing. However with web sockets (not widely supported) or socket.io (widely supported) you can detect when a connection is broken.

Comment: yes i have read the other post it seems to be the good way to do what i want to do thank you

Comment: i find an other wpost really smart i think, add "async:false", in the request parameter, browser waits till xhr completed work for me so thx again

Comment: Ah, that's also a good idea. Never thought of that. Just make sure it works in all browsers, it still relies on the browser to wait. However, even if the browser doesn't wait for the reply, just executing the ajax call is enough for your PHP mail script to work.